# unsecuredly or unsecurely?

Tags: word-choice

Which is the correct form of [unsecured](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unsecured) to use in the below sentence ?

1. [Unsecurely](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unsecurely%22&tbm=bks)
2. [Unsecuredly](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unsecuredly%22&tbm=bks)

> Sample Sentence: "Right over the center of the chamber, lay an earthen
> pot balanced ____________ on the ropes"

First of all, I am not sure if there is a difference between the two (Is there?). Both forms seem to be valid usage searching on google books and I am not sure if choosing one over the other modifies the meaning or is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Where does this sample sentence come from?

Comment: @Eden0516: I am writing it to describe a scene but was confused on which word would go there...

Comment: In merriam-webster you can only find unsecurely. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/securely#other-words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Unsecured” is an adjective that I would say does not directly translate well into an adverb. While “unsecured” is used to describe something that isn’t protected or firmly situated, the adverb “insecurely” can be used to describe an action that is unstable and not very firm.

“Unsecure” in itself is not a word, while “insecure” is.

Comment: so, if "unsecure" is not a word, then does it mean that "unsecurely" is invalid ?

Comment: @user96551 yep. as far as I know, “unsecurely” is not a word.